# ldap connection error, getting detail sub error code

Tags: java, ldap

doing this sort of connection seems to work if everything is ok with the user

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, someUrl);
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, commonName);
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

InitialLdapContext ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
    return true;
} catch (javax.naming.AuthenticationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (NamingException ex) {
     logger.warn("LDAP NamingException looking for user - " + 
          username + ": " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
return false;
```

But if the user is invalid, we just get an error like:
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: LDAP: error code 49
which does not tell the difference between invalid pass vs expired account etc.

I read that you could try and do a reconnect instead and then do getResponseControls() to get access to the detailed error that actually occurred, such as:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, someUrl);

InitialLdapContext ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
    // set the user/pass they entered
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, commonName);
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    ctx.reconnect(null);
    return true;
} catch (javax.naming.AuthenticationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    try {
       Control[] controls = ctx.getResponseControls();
       if (controls == null) {
          logger.debug("response controls  = null", ex);
       } else {
           logger.debug("response controls  = " + controls.toString(), ex);
       }
   } catch (NamingException ex1) {
       logger.error("error decoding respponsecontrols", ex);
   }
   return false;
} catch (NamingException ex) {
     logger.warn("LDAP NamingException looking for user - " + 
          username + ": " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

but when I do this, controls is null.

anyone ever done this successfully?

Comment: the place I read about using a reconnect() to get access to the ctx object is:  http://bb10.com/apache-directory-user/2011-11/msg00057.html  But as I said, this does not seem to be working as the ctx.getResponseControls() is null.  Look forward to any thoughts anyone might have.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Many directory servers use the "invalid credentials" (49) to indicate a problem with the account, that the account, does not exist or with the authentication. Generally, it is best not to indicate that an account does not exist or is locked (which also indicates its existence) because an attacker would then know the account existed.

Comment: I agree that I would not share this info with the end users entering the user/pass.  But we need it for internal debugging on our server.

Comment: These are the codes we are looking for:  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1155616